# magento image import in csv

Tags: magento, csv

I am using magento enterprise edition 1.12 and in that there is no import folder inside media folder. so, i have created one folder named import inside media.
Then, I have tried to put all the images in to media/import, and in `CSV` file for particular `SKU` i have passed `/example.jpg` for the title image.
But, After importing products, when i try to see that image from admin while editing product. i am not able to see that.
Can anyone please suggest for it.

Comment: And here one more thing i have found is, i can see those images on the front-end side, but not from the admin side....while importing i have set the thumbnail as well as small images...can i do something for it ?

Answer (score 1):

try to go through a checklist:

1) make sure media/import/example.jpg exists
2) make sure you put your string under the column header "**image**" (sometime people tend to use _image or something like that. I think this comes from magento export format)
3) try to change the products' name in your CSV and see if it changed in DB after import (this will indicate if import process is working at all at least for "name" field)
4) make sure media/catalog folder and sub-folders have writable permissions (chmod 777 media/ -R to make sure). It must copy files to that folders during import, so wrong permissions might be the reason

This is going to at least help to localize the issue

Comment: Thanks rob for your reply, i have checked with as per above checklist and all are working fine then also image is not imported.

Comment: I've added also a point about permissions to media/catalog, check this also

Answer (score 0):

To make it show on the admin side, we need to add price name for media_gallery as well we have to make it enable by putting 0, 1 or 2 as a base image, small, thumbnail.